# Locking behavior of MySQL VIEWs?

Tags: mysql

We're considering using a MySQL merge view in our application, and came across the following puzzling language in the documentation:

> A reason to choose TEMPTABLE explicitly is that locks can be released on underlying tables after the temporary table has been created and before it is used to finish processing the statement. This might result in quicker lock release than the MERGE algorithm so that other clients that use the view are not blocked as long.

The way I read this is that selects on merge views take out a read lock, but that doesn't seem right.  Can two clients read from a view simultaneously the way they can from a table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you create a view on MyISAM tables, SELECTs and UPDATEs are mutually exclusive, so a SELECT/UPDATE on the table would block any UPDATE/SELECT on the view. So you'd want to keep locks short.

On InnoDB, this is not a problem.

Comment: Sure, but this is more a function of how table locking works in general than anything introduced by views, right?  The language about "other clients" that "use the view" not being blocked makes me think the view itself it somehow locked, beyond the underlying tables(?)

Answer (score 0):

The way I read it is that while it DOES take out a lock (it has to read the data, right?), it builds a TEMPTABLE, and then release the lock. Any work to be done after that can be done without the lock, and so the other clients can have their fun with the underlying tables.

The read lock might be released quicker this way.

Comment: I guess my specific question is this: "Can two clients read from a view simultaneously the way they can from a table?"  Updated to reflect -- I'm guessing the answer is "yes."